# Gridview and Excel sorting

Tags: asp.net, excel

Below is my requirement

I have a Gridview which displays Information about Employee. Employee Contains many fields
out of which important fields DateOfJoining, Salary and Name. THere are many articles to Export
data to Excel. So i am also using OpenXml to export the Data.  Using this i am able to export 
data to Excel. Once the report is opened in excel, i then apply filter on the result in the excel
if i sort dateofJoining it should be able to sort based on the date, if i sort salary i  should
be able to sort in either asc or desc. Similary actions i need to do it in Name column also.
I am using internal a DataTable  which is binding to GridView.

Problem is even if i format the DateofJoining column in the DataTable still when the excel sheet is opened
it appears in default format. So i would like to know why formatting is not happening in the excel sheet.
and why we are not able to sort the DateOfJoining column in the excel. Is it possible to format the data and
sorting function before the data is binding to excelsheet. Or do we have an option to format the columns 
after the excel sheet is opened. Please let me know any solution or any sample where i can solve this issue.

Any help would be more useful

Comment: Have you tried using the save-as dialogue from Excel? It sounds like you are saving your file in a different format from the standard .xlsx format. Try saving the file as .xlsx and re-opening it and see if that works.

Comment: it is save .xlsx extension only

Comment: Then sounds like a "reformat on update" kind of thing. I am not familiar with the data connection, but perhaps there is a checkbox you can uncheck in there?